# Is there a way to password protect minimized windows in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

If I have some open images and documents in minimized position I want to be able to maximize them only after entering a password, don't want my family members see them but can't constantly open and re-open them.

Comment: While not quite what you are asking, you could set a password on your account and get your family to use a different user account then use Fast User Switching to avoid the need to close anything: https://www.lifewire.com/switching-between-users-in-windows-7-3506973

Comment: And of course protect these sensitive photos from being accessed by the other account. ;)

Comment: Also, I should mention: Native to windows, No, this cannot be done. You would need to replace the taskbar with another program or use a program that would modify the behavior of the taskbar, but I don't know any program that can do this. An alternative solution is much better.